# Div wider than container rotation off center

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a div that is covers the browser window diagonally. See example here:
[image: ideal display]

This is my CSS:

```
.shape {
  height: 100%;
  width: 150%;
  transform: rotate(25deg);
}
```

This is my actual result:
[image: actual result]

I've tried a bunch of different things using transformOrigin and setting top and left of the div, but nothing seems to work to have this div centered diagonally across the browser.

Comment: Maybe you can try to add transform: `translateY(negativevalue);`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add these: **transform-origin: center;**

Also when width is more than 100% you need to move content its centered before rotate. Like **Position: absolute; left: -25%;**

```css
    body {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    .frame {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        background: #EFEFEF;
    }
    .rotated {
      position: absolute;
      left: -25%;
      width: 150%;
      height: 100%;
      border: 2px solid blue;
      transform: rotate(25deg);
      transform-origin: center;
    }
```

```html
      <div class='frame'>
          <div class='rotated'></div>
      </div>
```